# How to logout from Google+ Account?

Tags: java, android, oauth, google-plus, google-oauth

After signin up with Google plus on an Android app.

How can I logout, so I can sign in with another account.

Don't know if `GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken` is the answer or not...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [Google+ sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) (and you should - the work flow is much better, both for developers and users), then you can sign out the user by following the [guide's example](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#sign_out_the_user):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
        if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I never get isConnected() == true.

Comment: Furthermore, I cannot get the dialog to choose another account once I've signed in & out

Comment: I'm sure disconnected, but cannot get the dialog again

Comment: If you never get `isConnected()==true`, then your `onConnected()` must never have been called, hence you were not fully connected in the first place. Check your connection result for any possible errors.

Comment: It's correctly connected because I can get the access token and all.... but when I try again it tells me it's not connected

Comment: This might help: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/03/common-problems-with-google-sign-in-on.html

Comment: Did you get a valid token? If you didn't register your API Console project correctly and correctly specify a package name and SHA1 hash, its possible to run into issues where it "seems" like you connected, but in reality have not.