# Code for logout from Facebook in android

Tags: android, android-json

I am using customize Facebook login button .this is my code. I'm using session manager to store email and name for entire app.I have used logout button in third activity .

**How to logout from Facebook**

```
public void FB_Login(View view){

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

       LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
               new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
//                       AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions();
//                       Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
//                       String firstName = profile.getFirstName();
//                       System.out.println(profile.getProfilePictureUri(20,20));
//                       System.out.println(profile.getLinkUri());

                       // App code
                       AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions();

                       GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                               loginResult.getAccessToken(),

                               new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onCompleted(
                                           JSONObject object,
                                           GraphResponse response) {
                                       // Application code
                                       try {
                                           email = object.getString("email");

                                           name=object.getString("name");

// Creating user login session
                                           // For testing i am stroing name, email as follow
                                           // Use user real data
                                           session.createLoginSession(name, email);

                                           // Staring MainActivity
                                            if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
                                                in = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, HomeSearchActivity.class);
                                                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                                                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                                                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                startActivity(in);

                                                finish();

                                            }
                                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                       }
                                       Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                   }
                               });
                       Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                       parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                       request.setParameters(parameters);
                       request.executeAsync();

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancel() {
                       // App code
                       Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                       // App code
                       Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
                   }
               });


}
```

Anyone help me. please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can logout from `Facebook` using `Facebook Graph API`.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks..but  how two overcome from two log out (face book and google plus) in single button click. i have two customized login buttons for both fb and gplus. i want to handle logout functionality.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444539/how-to-logout-from-google-account for logging out from gplus.

Answer (score 2):

At First, You need to **`Initialize SDK`**:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Then

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

[Courtesy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/)